# Spring+hibernate vs hibernate configuration. Cause of UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported by BasicDataSource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, configuration, datasource

Initially I used only hibernate

And I had  following `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>     
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/...</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">XXX</property> 
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>        

        //mapping
        ...

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And It works good:

after I include *Spring* and then configuration look so:

```
...
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/..." />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value=XXX /> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    </bean>
...
```

after it I see in console:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported by BasicDataSource
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1432)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
```

After I tried to remove

```
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">XXX</property>
```

from `hibernate.cfg.xml` and I don't see exceptions.

Can you explain what is the cause of this problems?

Initially I thought that problem that I shouldn't duplicate information in different configurations but now I see that for example `url` define inside `dataSource` and inside `hibernate.cfg.xml`

Please clarify this *Spring + Hibernate* magic.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In latest version getConnection(User,Password) method is not supported.

It will helps you : 
Replace

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource
```

with

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
```

Comment: Now I have a working application! I just want to understand cause of problem

Comment: Your suggestion is replacing a fully fledged connection pool with something that doesn't cache connections at all. Users should not do this in production.

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that with:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
```

You're not provided with connection pooling!

I would recommend to move to Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool.

That is by now IMHO the most efficient one.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
```

It requires the dependency

```
org.apache.tomcat tomcat-jdbc
```

Check documentation:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The `BasicDataSource` class will connect using its own `url`, `username` and `password` parameters. Session factory will use already configured data source. Therefore as a result the `url`, `username` and `password` parameters are overridden. Just ditch those connection parameters in `hibernate.cfg.xml` because they are managed by the `dataSource` bean.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and after above solution I got a destroy method 'close' not found error or something along those lines.

However, it does appear that getConnection(user, password) is the underlying issue here. When I commented out the connection.username and connection.password in the hibernate.cfg.xml everything works fine.

Correction: I should clarify that I moved the user name and password to the appContext like so

```
 <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    p:url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/my_schema"
    p:username="root"
    p:password="mypassword">
</bean>
```