# Two MySQL data source configuration on Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, spring, apache, tomcat

I want to create two data sources with Apache Tomcat v7.0.54. The below code is represent two data sources configuration

```
    <Context>
      <Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                   maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
                   username="javauser" password="javadude" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                   url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest"/>

   <Resource name="jdbc/TestDB1" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                   maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
                   username="javauser1" password="javadude1" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                   url="jdbc:mysql://localhost1:3306/javatest1"/>
    </Context>
```

Now I want to add the second data source which is different mysql server. Actually I added the second one and when I start tomcat connection is successful. But when I try to execute any query I got the below error

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported by
>   BasicDataSource

How can I fix this problem? I also use Spring framework.

**spring section**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure as beans -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter"/>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource1" jndi-name="jdbc/TestDB" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource2" jndi-name="jdbc/TestDB1" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />    

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory1" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="test_pu" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    </bean>
         <bean id="entityManagerFactory2" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="test_pu" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory1"/>
    </bean> 
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
  <description>MySQL Test App</description>
  <resource-ref>
      <description>DB Connection</description>
      <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestDB</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
  <resource-ref>
      <description>DB Connection</description>
      <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestDB1</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="test_pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
         <!--entity mapping -->   
         <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="MySQL"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="false"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="NONE"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Complete error:**

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported by BasicDataSource
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1062)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at classes.session.SessionCreate.buildSessionFactory1(SessionCreate.java:24)
    at classes.session.SessionCreate.<clinit>(SessionCreate.java:9)
    at classes.verifydata.CheckUniqueUserPass.uniqueUserPass(CheckUniqueUserPass.java:16)
    at org.apache.jsp.DataGen.CheckUserPassAvailable_jsp._jspService(CheckUserPassAvailable_jsp.java:70)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

you can execute any query.

Comment: Please show the entire config, the code executing the query and the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I updated my question please check it.

Comment: Try to change the id on this line: <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSourceq" ...>. i.e. the second one could be <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSourceq2" ...>

Comment: @user6904265 this is my mistake I copy paste and forgot to change. In my config they are different

Comment: You also use hibernate? could you post also the hybernate configs in the case?

Comment: @user6904265 I don't use hibernate but I use persitence unit. I will update with persistence unit config file

Comment: Did you really use the URL "localhost1"? This cannot succeed although I don't know what the resulting error would be.

Comment: @niklasp it is just example.you use any host

Comment: Is `CheckUniqueUserPass` one of your class? could you post it? it seems that the error start from there.

Comment: I dont use this class. I dont know which library use this. Is there any way to change basic data source to drivermaneger class on tomcat config?

Answer (score 0):

In your stacktrace there is an attempt to connect to a Database by  Hibernate:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported by BasicDataSource
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1062)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178)
```

May be it is a third part library.. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672619/springhibernate-vs-hibernate-configuration-cause-of-unsupportedoperationexcept) post, it could be helpful.

Comment: I read this post but i dont know how to change this basic data source class to driver manager. I dont use any hibernate condiguration